# Ubuntu PPPoE connection timeout

Tags: linux, ubuntu, connection, timeout, pppoe

I am trying to setup my internet connection on Ubuntu 9, but I am having some dificulties with it.

I managed to get it working but it continuously disconnects and reconnects.
Here's what I get immediately after a connection :

```
solomongaby@solomongaby-laptop:~$ plog
May  2 12:16:34 solomongaby-laptop pppd[4133]: primary   DNS address 213.154.124.1
May  2 12:16:34 solomongaby-laptop pppd[4133]: secondary DNS address 193.231.252.1
May  2 12:16:37 solomongaby-laptop pppd[7313]: PAP authentication succeeded
May  2 12:16:37 solomongaby-laptop pppd[7313]: peer from calling number 00:10:18:2C:07:60 authorized
May  2 12:16:37 solomongaby-laptop pppd[7313]: not replacing existing default route through ppp4
May  2 12:16:37 solomongaby-laptop pppd[7313]: Cannot determine ethernet address for proxy ARP
May  2 12:16:37 solomongaby-laptop pppd[7313]: local  IP address 79.119.100.50
May  2 12:16:37 solomongaby-laptop pppd[7313]: remote IP address 10.0.0.1
May  2 12:16:37 solomongaby-laptop pppd[7313]: primary   DNS address 213.154.124.1
May  2 12:16:37 solomongaby-laptop pppd[7313]: secondary DNS address 193.231.252.1
solomongaby@solomongaby-laptop:~$ plog
May  2 12:16:37 solomongaby-laptop pppd[7313]: not replacing existing default route through ppp4
May  2 12:16:37 solomongaby-laptop pppd[7313]: Cannot determine ethernet address for proxy ARP
May  2 12:16:37 solomongaby-laptop pppd[7313]: local  IP address 79.119.100.50
May  2 12:16:37 solomongaby-laptop pppd[7313]: remote IP address 10.0.0.1
May  2 12:16:37 solomongaby-laptop pppd[7313]: primary   DNS address 213.154.124.1
May  2 12:16:37 solomongaby-laptop pppd[7313]: secondary DNS address 193.231.252.1
May  2 12:16:50 solomongaby-laptop pppd[5214]: PPP session is 873
May  2 12:16:50 solomongaby-laptop pppd[5214]: Connected to 00:10:18:2c:07:60 via interface eth0
May  2 12:16:50 solomongaby-laptop pppd[5214]: Using interface ppp7
May  2 12:16:50 solomongaby-laptop pppd[5214]: Connect: ppp7 <--> eth0
```

But after like 3-4 minutes I get disconnected and it says something like 
unsuccesful 4 echo responses
link is not connected
modem disconected.

```
May  3 10:24:49 solomongaby-laptop pppd[2295]: No response to 4 echo-requests
May  3 10:24:49 solomongaby-laptop pppd[2295]: Serial link appears to be disconnected.
May  3 10:24:49 solomongaby-laptop pppd[2295]: Connect time 5.6 minutes.
May  3 10:24:49 solomongaby-laptop pppd[2295]: Sent 948 bytes, received 952 bytes.
May  3 10:24:55 solomongaby-laptop pppd[2295]: Connection terminated.
May  3 10:24:55 solomongaby-laptop pppd[2295]: Modem hangup
```

and then it reconnects but it takes a while to do it.

Can you guys help me make sense of this.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: "something like unsuccesfull 4 echo responses" is no error message. Please post the full log, so we can help you.

Comment: i added the exact logs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other side of the PPP link probably dosen't support LCP echo. You often see this with cellphone / cellular data card PPPoE implementations.

Put this line in the relevent ppp options file and try again:

```
lcp-echo-interval 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it work (can you use it/surf) for those 3-4 minutes ?

I really am no ppp/pppoe expert, but this looks just twisted:

> May  2 12:16:37 solomongaby-laptop pppd[7313]: local  IP address 79.119.100.50
>   May  2 12:16:37 solomongaby-laptop pppd[7313]: remote IP address 10.0.0.1

Can you maybe try to sniff the traffic with wireshark ?

If you are really lucky, your modem offers some debugging. Mine had syslog-output, which was easily configured.

Answer (score 0):

The remote PPP address is ok, some carriers like it that way.

The "not replacing existing default route" has me wondering if you're not being disconnected for idle on the ISP (or more unlikely, modem) end, as that indicates it's not being used as your main IP connection.

The next thing to check would be to get SNR data and the L2 logs from the modem if possible.